# Specify a method in a rule definition, such that a certain character class can be recognized

Tags: antlr4

When you write a lexer grammar for ANTLR, is it possible to specify a method, that decides, if a read character should be accepted by a rule?

For example something like:

```
WS  :   x = . [ only accept, iff Character.isWhitespace($x.text[0])==true] -> skip
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using semantic predicates:

```
WS : . {Character.isWhitespace(getText().charAt(0))}?
     -> skip
   ;
```

**But it won't be fast.**